# How to make a punch pose

Tags: rigging

I tried to rig my hand as good as possible. With the riggify addon. I tried to roll the finger to give a punch pose.

[image]

[image]

when scale the widgets all the fingers get mix with each other. I tried with copy rotation. Nothing work. Any suggestion or help where im going wrong and cant make a good pose of **PUNCH**

[image]

[Punch pose](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hand-signs-punch-fist-isolated-white-background-42833718.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since the fingers come in at different angles, it would probably be best to animate each bone individually.
[image]

Comment: can u plz share in detail how it works. blend file attach in the question

Comment: So remove any copy rotations or constraints from the bones and if possible revert them to standard bones instead of circle bones, (if you like them it's fine, I just haven't used that sort of bone before) at that point you can manually pose each bone. I gave an example of 2 of the fingers in a .blend file I attached to my answer, I only did 2 fingers for an example.